# Handling duplicates in TreeSet

Tags: java, data-structures, heap, treeset

I was solving a question where we have to find median of every window(sliding window). I know that treeset doesn't allow duplicates. So I wrote a custom comparator to use the elements index instead of the value.

Below is the code:-

```
class Solution {

     static int a[];
     static TreeSet<Integer> minheap;
     static TreeSet<Integer> maxheap;

     static class comp implements Comparator<Integer>
     {
         public int compare(Integer x,Integer y)
         {
             if(a[x]<a[y]) return -1;
             if(a[x]>a[y]) return 1;
             return 1;
         }
     }

    static class comp1 implements Comparator<Integer>
     {
         public int compare(Integer x,Integer y)
         {
             if(a[x]>a[y]) return -1;
             if(a[x]<a[y]) return 1;
             return 1;
         }
     }

     public void balance()
     {
         if(maxheap.size()>minheap.size()+1)
         {
             int temp=maxheap.pollFirst();
             minheap.add(temp);
         }
     }

     public void addNum(int num) {
        maxheap.add(num);
        balance();
        if(!maxheap.isEmpty() && !minheap.isEmpty() && a[maxheap.first()]>a[minheap.first()])
        {
            int temp1=minheap.pollFirst();
            int temp2=maxheap.pollFirst();

            minheap.add(temp2);
            maxheap.add(temp1);
        }
    }

    public double findMedian() {
        int size=maxheap.size()+minheap.size();
        if(size%2==1) return a[maxheap.first()];
        else return ((double)a[maxheap.first()] + a[minheap.first()])/2;
    }

    public double[] medianSlidingWindow(int[] nums, int k) {
        minheap=new TreeSet<Integer>(new comp());
        maxheap=new TreeSet<Integer>(new comp1());

        a=new int[nums.length];
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
            a[i]=nums[i];

        double ans[]=new double[nums.length-k+1];

        int j=0;

        for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
            addNum(i);

        for(int i=k;i<nums.length;i++)
        {
            ans[j++]=findMedian();
            if(minheap.contains(i-k))
                minheap.remove(i-k);    
            else
                maxheap.remove(i-k);
            balance();
            addNum(i);
        }

        ans[j++]=findMedian();
        return ans;
    }
}
```

In both the comparators, I return 1 when both values are same to break the ties as otherwise, treeset will consider them as same if I return 0. It is behaving weirdly if I use that statement. However, if I replace "return 1" with "return y-x" when both values are equal, it works fine.

Can someone help me understand this behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `return 1;` statement breaks the contract of the `Comparator`'s `compare` method, since it means that if `a[x]==a[y]`, `compare(x,y)` will return `1` and `compare(y,x)` will also return `1`, and break the `sgn(compare(x, y)) ==-sgn(compare(y, x))` requirement.

Comment: So is the behaviour undefined in that case ?

Comment: @Zephyr the behavior of what? Some sort implementations will throw an exception when they detect that the `Comparator` they are using violates the contract.

Comment: Actually I didn't get any exception. After invoking balance method, I was getting 4 elements in total after inserting only 3 elements when I returned 1.

Comment: @Zephyr do what did you mean by `It is behaving weirdly if I use that statement.`?

Comment: After inserting elements {5,2,2} using addNum() method,  size of minheap+size of maxheap should be 3 but I was getting 4 without any exception.